# lateinit property bitmap has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

So I have started to use View Model .

The following code is the Code of View Model:

```
 @HiltViewModel
 class Admin_Verif_VM  @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Admin_Verif_rp

    ) : ViewModel(){
private lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
fun verify(doc_name: String,uid:String){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        repository.verify(doc_name,uid)

    }
}
fun retrive(doc_name : String,uid: String): Bitmap?{
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
         bitmap = repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)!!
        
    }
    return bitmap
}


}
```

So from View Model I am making call to My Repository Which looks Like as Follows:

```
interface Admin_Verif_rp {
suspend fun verify(doc_name: String,uid:String)
suspend fun retrive(doc_name:String,uid:String): Bitmap?
}
```

A simple Interface which I implemented in Repository Implementation which is as follows:

```
class Admin_Verif_rp_imp : Admin_Verif_rp{


override suspend fun verify(doc_name: String,uid:String) {
    val query = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").whereEqualTo("UID", "$uid").get()
        .await()
    val array = query.first().toObject(docretreving::class.java).Pending
    val len = array.size-1
    val list = arrayListOf<String>()
    val list2 = arrayListOf<String>()

    for (i in 0..len){
        if (array[i]=="Passport"){
            list2.add(array[i])
            val query3 = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").document("$uid")
            query3.update(
                "Verified" , list2
            )
        }
        else{
            list.add(array[i])
        }
    }
    val query2 = Firebase.firestore.collection("profiles").document("$uid")
    query2.update(
        "Pending" , list
    )
  }

override suspend fun retrive(doc_name:String,uid: String) : Bitmap? {
    var bitmap : Bitmap? = null

val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference?.child("/image/${uid}/$doc_name")
    val localfile = File.createTempFile("tempImage", null)
        storageRef.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
         }
    return bitmap


            }

}
```

So explaining the complete flow what is going on here is , Basically I have a function in my repo implementation which I am calling from my Interface[repo] which again is called From view model. I want that function to return me a bitmap which I can use in UI page to set image. The bitmap will be retrieved from Firebase Storage. So for that I created A variable in my View Model named bitmap. Than inside that view models function I initialized the bitmap and tried returning it. But the app crashes and displays the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.adminv1, PID: 19486
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property bitmap has not been initialized
    at com.example.alliaise_adminv1.Admin.Admin_Verif_VM.retrive(Admin_Verif_VM.kt:28)
    at 
 com.example.alliaise_adminv1.Admin_Verification.onViewCreated(Admin_Verification.kt:38)
```

Basically Inside My View Model in the second Function which is retrieve() I am having the error in that line:

```
bitmap = repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)!!
```

How do I solve this...

Answer (score 3):

That happen because your function returning the bitmap before the bitmap is ready , because you call `repository.retrive(doc_name,uid)!!` in different thread ,the function will call `return` immediately after it launch the coroutine, it will not wait until the coroutine (the job) is finish.

**My solution**

**In viewModel**

Flow version

```kotlin
// you can use MutableStateFlow / LiveData
var bitmapFlow: Flow<Bitmap?> = emptyFlow()

fun retrive(doc_name : String,uid: String){
   bitmapFlow = flow {
      emit(retrive(doc_name,uid))
   }
}
```

StateFlow version

```kotlin
private var _bitmapFlow = MutableStateFlow<Bitmap?>(null)
val bitmapFlow = _bitmapFlow

fun retrive(doc_name : String,uid: String){
   viewModelScope.launch{
      bitmapFlow.value = retrive(doc_name,uid)
   }
}
```

**Activity/Fragment**

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){
   viewModel.bitmapFlow.collect { bitmap:Bitmap? ->
     imagaeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
  }
}
```